# MySQL join on multiple columns - clearer question format

Tags: mysql, join, multiple-columns

I'm going to try and make a post that follows the guidance. I hope it is easier to follow than my last effort.

I am trying to create some descriptive strings from the numeric data in the view (opp_team_scout) below for output in an online game.

[image: VIEW opp_team_scout]

I would like to give each team a verbal description for each skill - from the table (rank_descriptions) below.

[image: TABLE rank_descriptions]

The below code works (for a single attribute).

[image: Query 1]

[image: Query 1 output]

However I need to do this for 30+ attributes. When I try for more than 1 attribute the query fails.

[image: Query 2]

[image: Query 2 output]

Can anyone help? (and is this a better question format?)

Expected result table:

[image: Expected result table - as requested]

Comment: Can you add expected result table also, like you have added how it works for single column, but how you are expecting it to look after joining multiple columns.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Added.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You message says it all, y´join join two tables with the same name, so use ALIASES to compensate and differentiate them. Also you can use alias for all tables and save so time tipeng

```
select
    r.rank, descriptionl, o1.team_name as finishing, o2.team_name as longshots

 from rankdescriptions r
    left join opp_team_scout o1 on r.rank = o1.finishing 
    left join opp_team_scout i2 on r.rank = o2.long_shots
```

And please don't post images post text see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't work either though. .....#1052 - Column 'team_name' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: no problem, simply add the two new tablenames, see updated answer

Comment: Its done it!!!  Thank you.... time to jump around the room celebrating.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like finishing is a kind-of a foreign key of rank, if so you can join the tables on the field. something like this.

SELECT d.description_1, o.team_name FROM rank_descriptions d
   INNER JOIN opp_team_scout o
   ON d.rank = o.finishing

Comment: Thanks, this works with one variable, but not for more than one (as in the desired output added). Maybe it is impossible in SQL - so easy with VLookup in Excel.